# Cordova missing ANDROID_HOME variable to emulate

Tags: android, cordova

How can I get the emulator working? Cordova missed the ANDROID_HOME environment variable, but it is set as the terminal output below shows

In NetBeans works only debug by using the browser of the device, but not the emulation of the app as APK

```
yves@dell-xps:~/NetBeansProjects/moTion$ sudo cordova emulate
[sudo] password for yves: 
Running command: /home/yves/NetBeansProjects/moTion/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator
ERROR: Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
Error: /home/yves/NetBeansProjects/moTion/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
yves@dell-xps:~/NetBeansProjects/moTion$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/yves/Android/Sdk
```

Comment: what the result of `ls /home/yves/Android/Sdk` ?

Comment: add-ons  build-tools  docs  extras  platforms  platform-tools  samples  SDK Readme.txt  sources  system-images  temp  tools